# Silverlight charts with x and y axis label

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have a columnseries chart and its working fine,But i would like to add **Month** as Master Label in x -axis and **No of Issue** as Master Label in y - axis.

```
    <toolkit:Chart  Title="Issue Occurrence Trend">
        <toolkit:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}" AnimationSequence="Simultaneous"   IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}"  DependentValueBinding="{Binding NoIssue}"  >
        </toolkit:ColumnSeries>
    </toolkit:Chart>
```

Need help on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this ?

```
<toolkit:Chart  Title="Issue Occurrence Trend">

<toolkit:Chart.Axes>
<toolkit:CategoryAxis Title="Month" Orientation="X" />
<toolkit:CategoryAxis Title="No of Issue" Orientation="Y" />
</toolkit:Chart.Axes>

<toolkit:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}" AnimationSequence="Simultaneous"   IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Month}"  DependentValueBinding="{Binding NoIssue}"  >
</toolkit:ColumnSeries>
</toolkit:Chart>
```

Comment: This way :
CategoryAxis xAxis = this.chart.ActualAxes.Where(a => a.Orientation == AxisOrientation.X).FirstOrDefault() as CategoryAxis;
            xAxis.Title = "title";

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.One more After setting title the No of Issue values shows in right side of charts.